# Get URL of opened tab / tabs from terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, google-chrome

I have a tab open in Google Chrome. Is it possible to get or check it's url from terminal? If not, how about automator script?

Will also be satisfied with a title.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get the URL or Title of a Tab within Google Chrome via the command line, in a Terminal you can use `osascript` to either execute AppleScript *statements* or a *programfile*.

To see what is available in the Google Chrome AppleScript Dictionary, the dictionary can be opened and reviewed in the Script Editor using the File > Open Dictionary... command.

Here's a simple example to get the URL of the first Tab of the frontmost Google Chrome window:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Google Chrome" to get URL of tab 1 of window 1'
```

For the Title under the same conditions:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Google Chrome" to get title of tab 1 of window 1'
```

To get them both at the same time, under the same conditions:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Google Chrome" to get {title, URL} of tab 1 of window 1'
```

Depending on exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish the *statements* can be more complex and handle multiple Tabs and or Windows, etc.  Although this is where using `osascript` to call a *programfile* verses using `-e statement` will probably be easier.

---

Here's the output from Terminal when this page is the target Tab:

```
$ osascript -e 'tell application "Google Chrome" to get URL of tab 1 of window 1'
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232565/get-url-of-opened-tab-tabs-from-terminal
$ osascript -e 'tell application "Google Chrome" to get title of tab 1 of window 1'
osx - Get URL of opened tab / tabs from terminal - Ask Different
$ osascript -e 'tell application "Google Chrome" to get {title, URL} of tab 1 of window 1'
osx - Get URL of opened tab / tabs from terminal - Ask Different, http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232565/get-url-of-opened-tab-tabs-from-terminal
$
```

Comment: Very handy. Slight variation for Safari: `tell application "Safari" to get {name, URL} of tab 1 of window 1` although for some reason the URL is often "missing value".