# Get URL of opened Firefox tabs from terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, firefox

I am trying to get the url of all opened Firefox tabs from terminal using the solution given [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232565) which describes how to do so for chrome. I tried the following:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Firefox" to get URL of tab 1 of window 1'
```

Which is a slight modification of the following solution for Chrome:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Google Chrome" to get URL of tab 1 of window 1'
```

However I get this error:

```
41:46: syntax error: A number can’t go after this property. (-2740)
```

Note that I have tried this for Safari and Chromium and it works for both just as it does for Google Chrome.

Comment: Sans very basic _commands_, some of the ones found in the **Standard Suite** dictionary,  **Firefox** is essentially not **AppleScript** scriptable.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know about all tab URLs, but *since Firefox 87* you can use native AppleScript GUI scripting to get the **URL of the current tab**. That's because Firefox now has [support for VoiceOver](https://blog.mozilla.org/accessibility/voiceover-support-for-macos-in-firefox-87/) [1].

First enable Firefox support for VoiceOver by going to `about:config` and setting the `accessibility.force_disabled` property to `-1`.  Note that VoiceOver doesn't have to be enabled, only the support in Firefox. (Extra info at [2].)

After that, you can use the following one liner:

```
osascript -e  'tell application "System Events" to get value of UI element 1 of combo box 1 of toolbar "Navigation" of first group of front window of application process "Firefox"'
```

Also, by iterating over the windows you could get the URLs of the frontmost tab of each window...

---

[1]: Enabling VoiceOver support makes Firefox expose the internal structure of its window for GUI scripting.
[2]: For extra info and a non-permanent option (toggling `AXEnhancedUserInterface` via AppleScript) look at [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=781090#c10).